# Where are tranform LWC tags to HTML tags: Browser or Server

Tags: lightning-web-components

Where are transform LWC proper tags, for example:

```
<lightning:button>
<lightning:accordion>
<lightning:card>
```

into the corresponding HTML tags rendered by the browser? I think is made in the browser. Anyone knows full documentation about how is this process and wich Javascript is responsible for that transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components are loaded from the server and rendered by the browser. Note that the top-level elements are **not** converted to "proper tags;" by the power of [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components), they are rendered natively by the browser. See, for example, the source from an app I wrote:

[image: Example DOM from a Lightning App]

This is pulled directly from the page's DOM state. If you're interested in the "secret sauce," you can check out [lwc.dev](https://lwc.dev/). The source code for LWC is open source, you can run it practically anywhere, even on your own computer, Heroku or AWS, etc.

There is some compilation that occurs on the server, but the browser is ultimately responsible for rendering the components.